# How do I know what iteration I'm in when using the Integer.times method?

Tags: ruby, loops

Let's say I have

```
some_value = 23
```

I use the `Integer`'s `times` method to loop.

Inside the iteration, is there an easy way, without keeping a counter, to see what iteration the loop is currently in?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, just have your block accept an argument:

```
some_value.times{ |index| puts index }
#=> 0
#=> 1
#=> 2
#=> ...
```

or

```
some_value.times do |index|
  puts index
end
#=> 0
#=> 1
#=> 2
#=> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```rb
3.times do |i|
  puts i*100
end
```

In this way, you can replace 3 with any integer you like, and manipulate the index i in your looped calculations.
My example will print the following, since the index starts from 0:

```
# output

0

100

200
```